# Release automating with Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins

I am actually searching a way with Jenkins to automate the releases of a javascript project but I'm completly lost... I have startted Jenkins, configured it a bit by installing plugins and import the git hub project but I absolutely don't see where to go next. I have to find a way to automate the releases of the project on changes and eventually run unit tests on it via jenkins.

If anyone could help, I would be grateful.

Comment: if you are using linux machine then use `rsync` to copy file to ur remote machine..... you can execute bash  script for that

Comment: this question is way too open, please read and execute some basic Jenkins job-creation tutorial (like: [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm)). Start with having a job do a git checkout and build. If you have that, you can configure the job to poll the git repo or you could try your hand at git hooks. You're mostly asking for a jenkins training which is not a question that can actually be answered here.

Comment: Thanks for the rapidity of your answers, I'll search base informations first